# Calculate the representation matrix of $L$ with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

### The Question

> With respect to the bases,
>
> $$a_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
>      1 \\
>      1 \\
>      1 \end{pmatrix},\ a_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
>      0 \\
>      1 \\
>      2 \end{pmatrix},\ a_3 =\begin{pmatrix}
>      1 \\
>      0 \\
>      0 \end{pmatrix} \text{of}\ \mathbb{R}^3$$
>
> $$b_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
>      -1 \\
>      2  \end{pmatrix},\ b_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
>      1 \\
>      -1  \end{pmatrix} \text{of}\ \mathbb{R}^2$$
>
> the linear mapping of $L:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is
> represented by the matrix:
>
> $$A =\begin{pmatrix}
>      1 & 0 & 3 \\
>      -2 & 2 & 0  \end{pmatrix}.$$
>
> a) Calculate the representation matrix of $L$ with respect to the
> standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2.$
>
> b) Give a basis of $c_1, c_2, c_3$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a basis $d_1, d_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $L$ is represented by the matrix
>
> $$A_0 =\begin{pmatrix}
>      1 & 0 & 0 \\
>      0 & 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> with respect to these bases.

### The Understanding

Can someone help me solve this task or at least explain me how it should be done. I don't understand this very well.

Comment: Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and use mathjax for future questions, as images cannot be searched on MSE. Also, what previous attempts have you done?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that we have a linear transformation from domain $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the co-domain $\mathbb{R}^2$.

(a) It is given that linear transformation L is represented by:

\begin{align}
A =\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 3 \\
     -2 & 2 & 0  \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Now we want to find the representation matrix for the linear transformation L with respect to the bases standard basis $\beta = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ and $\gamma = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.

\begin{align}
T((1,1,1)) = A\begin{pmatrix}
          1 \\
          1 \\
          1 \\ \end{pmatrix} 
          =\begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 0 & 3 \\
          -2 & 2 & 0  \end{pmatrix}
          \begin{pmatrix}
          1 \\
          1 \\
          1 \\ \end{pmatrix} 
          = \begin{pmatrix}
          4 \\
          0 \\
          \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
T((0,1,2)) = A\begin{pmatrix}
          0 \\
          1 \\
          2 \\ \end{pmatrix} 
          =\begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 0 & 3 \\
          -2 & 2 & 0  \end{pmatrix}
          \begin{pmatrix}
          0 \\
          1 \\
          2 \\ \end{pmatrix}
          = \begin{pmatrix}
          6 \\
          2 \\
          \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
T((1,0,0)) = A\begin{pmatrix}
          1 \\
          0 \\
          0 \\ \end{pmatrix} 
          =\begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 0 & 3 \\
          -2 & 2 & 0  \end{pmatrix}
          \begin{pmatrix}
          1 \\
          0 \\
          0 \\ \end{pmatrix}
          = \begin{pmatrix}
          1 \\
          -2 \\
          \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Now expressing these vectors as linear combinations of b1,b2,b3:

T(a1) = 4b1 + 8b2 (verify)

T(a2) = 8b1 + 14b2 (verify)

T(a3) = -1b1 + 0b2 (verify)

So the desired matrix:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
          4 & 8 & -1 \\
          8 & 14 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful, do you have any tip for b)?

Comment: @Erza So I take that you are convinced with the solution of part a? about part b, I need to check something, then I will add the solution to the post.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. For part a) I´ve done the task until there where you wrote (verify) in the same way as you did, but in the end I got the same Matrix as was given and I wasn´t sure about my solution, because I didn´t know that I should get the Matrix from these numbers (4 8), (8 14), (-1 0), so are you very sure it should be done in this way?

Comment: @Erza, yes, I'm positive. The procedure is to compute the a's using the linear transformation (because they are in the domain of L) after that, you need to express them as a linear combination of the b's. So after doing that, you will get the matrix that represents these changes. Clear?

Comment: Yes, clear. Thanks. And for example, if it´s a Matrix given with respect to Standardbases and we have to calculate the representation matrix of L with respect to other bases, it should be done in the same way right?

Comment: @Erza You are welcome. Yes, it is done in the same way.